# Can't get selenium to click button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

[Pic of the website's inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9uag.jpg)
[More in Depth pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VdJU.jpg)
My Code snippet

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
import requests
///
excel = driver.find_element_by_name('Excel')
excel.click()
```

I then get this when I try to run it, any help would be appreciated

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="Excel"]"}
```

Comment: Can you share the url? As Excel might be nested within some elements it might not be accessed directly. You can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354465/python-selenium-unable-to-click-button

Comment: I'm automating some work processes and this URL pertains to my work so I'd rather not share, i'm sure you understand. Is there any other type of information I could share that would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[mat-button] > span.mat-button-wrapper span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@mat-button]/span[@class='mat-button-wrapper']//span[text()='Excel']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the input, I did manage to find a different solution to my problem, but I did run your solution and it also worked!

Comment: I will have to read up on angular elements, as I did not know how to manage them, also made sure to upvote you

Answer (score 1):

**driver.find_element_by_name('Excel')** selects a tag with name='Excel'.

For example, it would find a tag like this:

```
<div name='Excel'>Hello</div>.
```

The CSS equivalent for find_element_by_name is [name="Excel"].

From the pic of your website's inspect element, it seems that you are trying to find an element with the text 'Excel' inside the div, so instead, you need to use the following function:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Excel')
```

Hope that helped!

For more on Python selenium webdriver, use [this link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html). It helped out a lot for me!

Comment: hello I just tried this method and got this error                               
 NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-7df6dff5dfa1> in <module>
     43 apply.click()
     44 sleep(3)
---> 45 excel = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Excel')
     46 excel.click()

Comment: Ah I see, I'm sorry I didn't realize you're clicking on a span. Clicking on link_text might only work on <a> tags. I would recommend you try out driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.mat-button-wrapper span') then!

Comment: Once do I print that to see the element?I had it set to click and it gave me the same error, sorry if im asking alot of questions, still brand new.

Comment: Hmmm... Seems like span isn't a clickable element actually. Do you absolutely need to click on it? If you really do, I recommend you look into how to do it in JavaScript because driver can execute JavaScript code using driver.execute_script(). However, if you simply do driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.mat-focus-indicator") I think it'll work fine too. Try the latter first.

Comment: When I ran that on the actual website it ended up clicking something else, probably shares that tag right? This button is used to download a report. Clicking on it initializes the download.

Comment: Alright fam I gotchu. driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.mat-focus-indicator:nth-child(3)"). This selects the button that is the third child of its parent, which is the Excel button if I'm not wrong.

Comment: aw damn I thought that would solve it but it ended up clicking the same thing as the last one

Comment: I also altered the last (3) and tried 1 and 2, and it kept clicking the same drop down arrow.

Comment: I don't think I know enough to help you unfortunately. I recommend you to go get the extension from your browser's web store Selenium IDE. Play around with it and it should help you find a way to select that button. I also realized that I should've mentioned that at the beginning, sorry I'm a new user so I'm a bit clumsy at helping.

Comment: ok when I click the button with the IDE recording it gives me the xpath 
 //button[3]/span/span                                                                                                   
 so then I did                                                                                                              excel = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[3]/span/span")
link.click()                                                                                                                                       this clicked on the same drop down as the line you sent me previously

Comment: I also can do  xpath=//button[contains(.,'Excel')]                                                     
But when I do driver.find_element_by_xpath it still clicks on the same drop down...

Comment: Damn, I really don't understand why even that doesn't work. Can you send me the code possibly through Google Drive or Github so that I can inspect it further?

Comment: Ah, ok ill upload to gethub later, but is the way I  did the driver.find_element_by_xpath correct?

Comment: ok so I managed to find a work around                                                                       excel = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[3]")
actions = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element_with_offset(excel, 20, 20)
actions.click()
actions.perform()

Comment:  oh nice that's smart you just move it to where you want it XD